# Distinct function somehow not giving back all types

Tags: distinct, orientdb

Feel free to check it on my latest project: http://arda-maps.org:2480 *arda arda* as login.

Now check [**select distinct(type) from Location**](http://arda-maps.org:2480/studio/index.html#/database/arda/browse/select%20distinct(type)%20from%20Location)

Here you get 8 records (River,Lake,Region,City,Island,House,Mountain,Hill). But actually there are way more...

To show you that the distinct somehow is not giving back all distinct we search for one specific vertex with another type:

[**select * from Location where name = "Citadel of Gondor"**](http://arda-maps.org:2480/studio/index.html#/database/arda/browse/select%20*%20from%20Location%20where%20name%20=%20%22Citadel%20of%20Gondor%22)

So am I using distinct in a wrong way. Or what could be the reason for the incomplete result list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. But if you try:

```
select distinct(type) from Location limit -1
```

you'll have all 64 distinct entrances.

Comment: Indeed that works but than it's totally buggy somehow. Thank you anyway. =)

Comment: Yes, it looks like it.

Comment: @kwoxer It seems buggy but actually works a bit differently, I try to explain in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the order the query parts are applied in the result set is not very obvious. You typed:

`select distinct(type) from Location`

and the orient studio applies a `limit 20` (unless you change that or include a different limit in your query). So the query that finally runs is

`select distinct(type) from Location limit 20`

Now, this could mean one of the two:

1. Find at most 20 locations and give me their distinct types
2. Find at most 20 distinct types of all locations

Obviously, what you expect is the 2nd and what happens is the 1st. The solution is to have inner queries so `limit` will explicitly apply on the outer query:

`select from (select distinct(type) from Location) limit 20`

This now clearly says, find me the distinct types of all locations and return me at most 20 (which is the same as (2))

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Yeah actually that could be the reason. I just looked up the first 20 entries and there taking the distinct. But @vitorenesduarte's Solution is way simplier. Anyway thanks.